# Accessing Jackson's identity info store

Tags: java, jackson

While Jackson is deserializing the object graph, is there any way to (legally) access the map where it stores objects annotated with @JsonIdentityInfo?

Answer (score 0):

The object that has the active mappings is `DeserializationContext`, which is passed to deserializers. I don't remember what exact access there is, but information should be available in some form.